# Delegate returning nil

Tags: xcode, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to use a protocol / delegate in swift, and while I'm not getting any errors it seems that my delegate is not being created.

Here is my code

Class 1

```
import UIKit

protocol GameViewSliding{
    func slideGameView()
}

class GameDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:GameViewSliding?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showOptions(sender: AnyObject) {

        println("button pressed")
        println(delegate)
        delegate?.slideGameView()
    }

}
```

Class 2 that conforms to the protocol

```
import UIKit

var currentHoleNumber:Int = 0
var parThree = false;
var parFive = false;

class GameViewController: UIViewController,  GameViewSliding{


var gameDetailsVC:GameDetailsViewController = GameDetailsViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println("inside the game class")
        gameDetailsVC.delegate = self
    }

    func slideGameView(){
        println("this is from the root controller")
    }

}
```

The delegate comes back nil, which is why I never get the println from Class2, just not sure why it's nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a reference in your `GameViewController` to the class `GameDetailsViewController` when it should be presented and set it's `delegate` in the following way :

```
gameDetailsViewController.delegate = self
```

And with that the delegate it's not `nil`, of course that set the reference in the `prepareForSegue` or any other method you use to present the other ViewController.

Comment: I updated my code, and made a reference to the GameDetailsVC, but when the println for the delegate is ran inside the showOptions function I still get nil

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there are some issues when setting the delegate up when using SplitViewController. The detailVC from the splitViewController can be acquired like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let detailNavigationController = splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
    let detailVC = detailNavigationController.topViewController as! DetailViewController

    detailVC.delegate = self
}
```

Another way is to set the delegate in the AppDelegate, the lines following after the SplitViewController is configured:

```
let masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
let masterVC = masterNavigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
let detailNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
let detailVC = detailNavigationController.topViewController as! DetailViewController

detailVC.delegate = masterVC
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem also. And I have checked I've already implemented the protocol, let the VC conform to the protocol, create delegate of this protocol. The only thing I forget to do is to set the identifier to the segue, when setting the delegate of the second VC to the first VC.

Comment: I mean I have done all the things for delegate and protocol to work.

Comment: Actually I have just copy/paste the code from one of my project. This means the code part of my project should be working. I set the initial view controller as the delegate of the next view controller inside the prepareForSegue function.  if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" {destinationVC.delegate = self}.     What I forgot is to set the identifier for the segue in the storyboard, which mean the whole setting delegate thing does not happen. That is why it failed.